# iframe prevent parent back button angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular8

we have website that on click load games in iframe, and on the back button my url changes and the game is closed. Recently I notice that on some games back button don't work, after clicking back button it flash on second and noting happens url stay the same. I tried to cache back button event but it's never triggered. We use Angular8. If anybody have idea what is happening please help?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want that **on click** your page go somewhere then use navigate on (click) event of button

```
 this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
```

If you want to stay at same page then make your button not clickable simple